# Is there any package for flutter that enable the feature of blocking and unblocking internet access to all application of devices?

Tags: flutter, networking, dart

Is there any package for flutter that enable the feature of blocking and unblocking internet access to all application of devices. like there will be one application built with flutter and it has access to enable and disable internet access to all other apps install in device.

Answer (score 0):

As I know you have to create a custom platform code https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

The is a project but I think it is only working with WIFI right now https://github.com/alternadom/WiFiFlutter